# cmake directories problem

Tags: cmake

I have two cmake-related problems: first, I can't make it to find the includes in the include folder, and it doesn't find the main.cpp file unless I place it in the same directory as the CMakeLists.txt. Can you please help me?

I have the following directory structure:

```
/TRT
 |
 +--- /src                 (bunch of .cpp files here)
       |
       +--- /include       (header files here)
```

The CMakeLists.txt is located in /TRT, main.cpp is located in /TRT/src, the includes are in /TRT/src/include.

I have written the following CMakeLists.txt and placed it in /TRT:

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 2.6 )
project(TRT)
add_subdirectory(src)
include_directories( $(TRT_SOURCE_DIR)/include )
add_executable( trt main )
target_link_libraries( glut )
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: where do u want to put your main.cpp ? in src ? include is it in the same level as src or in src ?

Comment: Hi Nadir, thanks for the comment, I have clarified my post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use the PARENT_SCOPE option.  Here's a basic example:
`#CMakeLists.txt in TRT/src

set(trtSources  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp PARENT_SCOPE)`

---

`#CMakeLists.txt in TRT

cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 2.6 )

project(TRT)

add_subdirectory(src)

include_directories( $(TRT_SOURCE_DIR)/src/include )

add_executable( trt ${trtSources} )

target_link_libraries( glut )`

Comment: It's weird, because cmake drops warnings (it says it can't find main.cpp), but generates the Makefile. But it still doesn't work, it won't find the includes.

Comment: I didn't notice your include directory was a subdirectory of src.  Change the include_directories statement to include_directories( $(TRT_SOURCE_DIR)/src/include )